# How to find memory consumption of VC++/MFC-App

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, memory-leaks, mfc, out-of-memory

I'm working on an Application in this Environment: Windows, Native, 32 Bit, Built with Visual Studio C++ and MFC, several Com-Dlls, ActiveX-Controls, libs.
When My App is running I see in the Windows-Taskmanager that its slowly but constantly consuming memory (about 10Kb per minute or about 1K per 10 "working-cycles" of my app) and I need to figure out where this consumption occurs.

Background information:

- the app has 2 states: idle and working. The memory consumption only occurs in working-state where constantly data is processed
- in working-state there is no user-input or any other external requests to the app
- I'm pretty sure that there is no problem with dynamic allocated memory (new, malloc) since I checked it already with Tools like MemPro (https://puredevsoftware.com/mempro) and there are no memory-leaks reported in the Debugger when I end the program
- So what I think is there are either some class-members (lists, maps, arrays,...) that are growing (but shouldn't) or the memoryconsumption occurs in an external component

So my questions are:

- Do you know any Tools that can track the memory usage
- I use Windows-Taskmanager and Sysinternals-Process-Explorer, but both show my memory in KBytes. Is there a way/tool to see it in bytes so I can see changes more quickly?
- how to get the current memory-usage of my app in code (I guess some windows-Api-call) so that I can encircle the problem via Debug-Outputs
- any other tips?

Comment: Despite the mempro have not found leaks I still believe you need a profiler that can compare memory snapshots (not sure about mempro but Deleaker can do that). So you could review the difference to understand where the memory is constantly allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a snapshot of your memory with `_CrtMemCheckpoint()` at any point, then you can compare two snapshots with `_CrtMemDifference()`.
Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2019 for details.